# Largest integer below any given non-negative fractional number

Tags: haskell, recursion, functional-programming, tail-recursion

How could I, using tail recursion, **find the largest interger below any non-negative fractional number**?

I have defined the function `largest :: Fractional f -> Int i` but don't see how I can use tail recursion in this case.

Comment: You cannot use `Fractional f -> Int i` since `Fractional` is a class, not a `data`. Do you by any chance mean `Fractional f => f -> Int`?

Comment: Well I can use anything as long as it's the signature of a function that can computes the largest integer below any non-negative fractional number.

Comment: @PierreP. He means that the signature you gave is invalid Haskell. The Haskell compiler would reject that signature, because of the errors in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any `Fractional` has a class defintion, like:

```
class Num a => Fractional a where
    fromRational :: Rational -> a
    -- ...
```

With:

```
type Rational = Ratio Integer
```

and:

```
(%) :: Integral a => a -> a -> Ratio a
```

I also assume that there is a type constraint such that we can *compare* two `f`s (of the `Fractional` instance). So what we can do is:

1. start with an accumulator set to `0`,
2. construct a `Rational` that has the value *accumulator+1*,
3. cast that `Rational` to the `f` type,
4. compare the constructed `f` with the given `f`,
5. if the value is greater than the given one, then we return the accumulator,
6. otherwise, we perform recursion by an incremented accumulator.

So in code this would look like:

```
import Data.Ratio((%))

largest :: (Fractional a, Ord a) => a -> Integer
largest v = largest' 0
    where largest' x | fromRational (x1%1) >= v = x -- increment is less than or equal, return x
                     | otherwise = largest' x1 -- if smaller, recursion
              where x1 = x+1 -- increment accumulator
```

This gives:

```
*Main Data.Ratio> largest (7%5)
1
*Main Data.Ratio> largest (21%5)
4
*Main Data.Ratio> largest (1%5)
0
```

If you want more freedom about the return type (any `Num`, you can add `fromIntegral` in the basecase):

```
import Data.Ratio((%))

largest :: (Fractional a, Ord a, Num b) => a -> b
largest v = largest' 0
    where largest' x | fromRational (x1%1) >= v = fromIntegral x -- increment is less than or equal, return x
                     | otherwise = largest' x1 -- if smaller, recursion
              where x1 = x+1 -- increment accumulator
```